# How to update single value inside array in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, state

I am creating a todolist with `react` and `redux` and when I update redux state array it doesn't re-render, My state is actually an array which contains objects, something like this:

```
[{index:1,value:'item1',done:false}, {index:2,value:'item2',done:false}]
```

What i want to do is on click i want to toggle the value of done to 'true',
But somehow I am unable to do that.

This is what I was doing in my reducer:

```
list.map((item)=>{
     if(item.index===index){
         item.done=!item.done;
         return [...state,list]
     }
```

But it doesn't re-render even though done keeps changing on clicking the toggle button.

It seems that somehow I am mutating the state.
please tell me where am I going wrong and what should I do instead.

Could you give examples of something similar. I can update state of simple arrays correctly, but doing it for an array containing  objects , is what's confusing me.
so, could you give examples of that?

Here's the full reducer code:

```
export default function todoApp(state=[],action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [...state,action.item];
        case 'TOGGLE_TODOS':
            const index = action.index;
            const list = state;

            list.map((item)=>{
            if(item.index===index){
                item.done=!item.done;

            }
            return [...state,list];
            });
        default:
          return state;    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It seems that somehow I am mutating the state.

Correct you are mutating the state, because in js, variable always get reference of object/array. In your case `item` will have the reference of each object of the array and you are directly mutating the value of `item.done`.

Another issue is you are not returning the final object properly, also you need to return value for each map iteration otherwise by default it will return `undefined`.

Write it like this:

```
case "TOGGLE_TODOS": 
    return list.map((item) => (
        item.index===index? {...item, done: !item.done}: item
    ))
```

Or:

```
case 'TOGGLE_TODOS':
    const index = action.index;
    const newState = [ ...state ];
    newState[index] = { ...state[index], done: !newState[index].done };
    return newState;
```

**Full Code:**

```
export default function todoApp(state=[], action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD_TODO':
            return [...state, action.item];
        case 'TOGGLE_TODOS':
            const index = action.index;
            return state.map((item) => (
                item.index===index? {...item, done: !item.done}: item
            ))
        default:
            return state;    
    }
}
```

Check this snippet:

```js
let list = [
    {done:true, index:0},
    {done:false, index:1},
    {done: true, index:2}
  ]

let index = 1;

let newList = list.map(item => (
    item.index===index? {...item, done: !item.done}: item
))

console.log('newList = ', newList);
```

Comment: could you give an example of array containing objects. because that's what's confusing me. I want to update just a property of the object and I'd like to know how to do that.

Comment: @faraz check the updated answer, let me know if have any doubt in that :)

Comment: so, in your code above. would you return state like this -->                             
return {...obj,newObj} ??

Comment: where you are getting confused, can you should full state code where you tried and what i will help you.

Comment: updated full reducer code - what I was doing originally.
it was changing the value of done to true and false accordingly but not rerendering.

Comment: check the updated answer, full code part try that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165915/discussion-between-faraz-and-mayank-shukla).

Answer (score 1):

Check out the documentation for [Array.prototype.Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

The callback function should return element of the new Array. Try this:

```
return list.map(item => {
  if (item.index === index) {
    return {
      done: !item.done
      ...item,
    }

  return item;
});
```

Comment: could you give an example of array containing objects. because that's what's confusing me. I want to update just a property of the object and I'd like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Although there already exist two correct answers, I'd like to throw `lodash/fp` in here as well, which is a bit more dense and readable and also doesn't mutate

```
import { set } from 'lodash/fp'

return list.map(item => {
    if (item.index === index) {
        return set('done', !item.done, item)
    }
    return item
}
```